# nuget.exe doesn't return all versions of specified package

Tags: nuget, nuget-package, nuget-server, nugetgallery

I'm using the latest stable version of nuget.exe (4.3.0) and attempting to get all versions of a package.

This returns only one version:

```
nuget.exe list OBeautifulCode.Math.HashCodeHelper -allversions -prerelease -includedelisted -source "https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json"
```

output:

```
OBeautifulCode.Math.HashCodeHelper 1.0.52
```

Same if I remove -prerelease and -includedelisted

nuget.org has multiple versions of this package (including delisted and pre-release and non-pre-release versions): [OBeautifulCode.Math.HashCodeHelper](https://www.nuget.org/packages/OBeautifulCode.Math.HashCodeHelper/)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This is a known bug: https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/6044